# average by row without considering the negative values

Tags: r, selection, average

I need to calculate the average among variables for the single units of my dataset. 
But, while doing it, I need to do not consider some values. 
To better explain, think like there are two units and three variables:

```
      V1    V2     V3
[1]   3     -2      4
[2]  -1      4      1
```

and you want to **calculate the average by row**, **without considering those negative values**:

=> mean(1row) = (3+4)/2

=> mean(2row) = (4+1)/2

Could anyone please give me the commands to do that in R?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

Use the apply function to take the mean of each row, with the stipulation that the values have to be greater than 0.

```
df=data.frame(V1=c(3,-1),V2=c(-2,4),V3=c(4,1));df

apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

Comment: Another solution would be `is.na(df) <- df <= 0; rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: `NA` is your friend :-) .  Note also that Joshua's method leaves you with a dataframe devoid of negative values should you wish to perform additional operations on your "desired" subset.